# samba share in windows 7 home - doesn't show up at all

Tags: windows-7, windows, samba

I've setup a simple linux machine with samba 3 on it.

I configured samba share to allow guest access. So no usernames or passwords required.

From my ubuntu laptop I can access share without problems, right under Network I see my server and I also see windows workgroup share right next to it.

But when I load in win7, and try to get to my box. It just doesn't do anything.

I read about Local Security Policy fix, that requires Network security: LAN Manager authentication level modification and since I have win7 home I had to tweak it from registry direct.

Despite fix, share doesn't show up.

p.s. I disabled firewall during test.

p.p.s. I've selected public network in win7 when I first connected to my home wifi. Could this be problem? should I change it to home instead?

p.p.p.s. under win7, I add path from my computer -> add a network location -> \mini.local\media\sd\torrents

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this can help. But I cannot ping win7 machine from server. Could be the root of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed router, and everything is PERFECT!

It was NAT router from ISP that was misocnfigured, and also locked so nobody could fix it.